# Laravel get and post to an external php controller with ajax

Tags: ajax, laravel, post, get, helper

I am working on laravel project and i need to make AJAX post to custom function in laravel, and get response to my custom view.

Atm i have

1. /app/Http/VatHelperController.php

   ```
   <?php

   namespace App\Http\Controllers;

   use Request;

   use App\Http\Requests;

   use App\Http\Response;

   use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

   class VatHelperController extends Controller
   {       
       public function recieve(){
           $data = '555';
           return View::make('clients.edit', $data);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Inside routes.php

   ```
    // Vatchecker get post
    Route::post('/vat', 'VatHelperController@receive');
    Route::get('/vat', 'VatHelperController@receive');
   ```
3. inside clients/edit.blade.php

   ```
    <div class="row">
    <form>
    <input type="text" id="input-vat">
    <input type="submit" id="btn-test-submit">
    </form>
    <p>Result :</p>
    <p class="test-result"></p>
    </div>

    <script>
        $('#btn-test-submit').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var vat_value = document.getElementById('input-vat').value;
            var url = "http://185.81.165.216/index.php/vat";
            if (vat_value !== "" && vat_value.length < 20){
                $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: vat_value,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', $("#token").attr('content'));},
                    done: function(data){
                       $('.test-result').text('done');
                    },
                    error: function(){
                        $('.test-result').text("didnt");
                    }
                })
                $('.test-result').text(vat_value);
            }
            else if (vat_value.length > 20){
                $('.test-result').text('Your entered value is to long. Max lenght 20 char.');
            }
            else{
               $('.test-result').text('You have to enter value.');
            }
                   $.get('index.php/vat', function(){
                console.log('response');
            });
        });
    </script>
   ```

My end goal is to make form and send data with post to a function inside helper and get response to js, and echo it inside table, the only thing i can't figure out is how to post and get inside laravel.

Comment: `vathelper` has to be a Controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this command while in main project directory:

```
php artisan make:controller VatHelperController
```

then add this to the routes/web.php

```
Route::post('/vat', 'VatHelperController@receive');
```

Then add this function to the VatHelperController:

```
public function receive (Request $request){

    // print all data sent
    print_r( $request->all() );
    // access particular data by:
    echo $request->input('name');

}
```

in the end you can add this bit of JS in the desirable view file:

```
window.onload = funtion () {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/vat",
      data: {name:"YourName"},
      success: function() {},
      dataType: "json"
    });
}
```

You can also use a bit blade variables in your JS code for example

```
data: {name: {{$php_var}} }
```

read more about PHP variables in blade templates [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#components-and-slots)

Comment: What do you mean, 404 when accessing /vat through ajax?

Answer (score 0):

There is some thing, that is a bit off in your code.

1. The `vathelper` does not look like a Controller. To be able to access it through HTTP, It has to be a Controller. Else the routing system cannot interact with it.
2. You don't have to autoload your classes. They are already autoloaded in the `\App` namespace.
3. `clients.vat` is a strange name. It'll make the browser think that it might be accessing a `.vat` file, whatever that is. You should call it `/clients/vat`